# is there a whitelist when forward auth in traefik 2.10

Tags: authentication, traefik

I am using traefik 2.10 to do the jwt token verify, I put the jwt token in header. Fisrt I created the middleware like this:

```
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: jwt-token-auth
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
spec:
  forwardAuth:
    address: >-
      http://dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:11014/post/auth/access_token/verify
```

then apply the auth forward middleware. what I am trying to do is ignore the login url when verify jwt token. this is how I doing it in Java api, I have checked the url in the check function like this:

```
public ResponseEntity verifyAccessToken(String accessToken, String authorizationHeader) {
        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        if(ignoreUrl.containsKey(path)){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("ok");
        }
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(accessToken)){
            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                accessToken = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            }
        }
        return AuthUtil.verifyAccessTokenGateway(accessToken);
    }
```

but it seems could not work. I could not get the exactly url request by user, the url is always `/post/auth/access_token/verify`. I have already defined the url that I want to ignored like this:

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> ignoreUrl = new HashMap<>(){
        {
            // texhub
            put("/texpub/user/login", 1);
            put("/texpub/user/reg", 1);
            put("/texpub/auth/access-token/refresh", 1);
        }
    };
```

what should I do to add the white list of ignored url? when user request `/texpub/user/login`, just return success.